# Ruby on Rails - Criteria - Mongoid - where condition with 2 by 2 columns

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, criteria

I'm working with RoR + MongoDB (Mongoid) and I need to apply a filter using or condition by 2 columns.

I saw some recommendations like this one but didn't work.

```
query = query.where(name: /#{attributes[:name]}/i).or(query.where(email: /#{attributes[:email]}/i))
```

If I use this one, looks like the or will be applied for all conditions:

```
query = query.where(name: /#{attributes[:name]}/i).or(email: /#{attributes[:email]}/i)
```

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: What do those queries generate and what is your desired result?

Comment: The result I got is: SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%mateus%' OR email LIKE '%mateus%'

I want this result: SELECT * FROM people WHERE (name LIKE '%mateus%' OR email LIKE '%mateus%')

I need that the "OR" be applied only for the name and email and not to the conditions applied after it.

Comment: This is already Mongoid's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the correct query should be:

```
query = query.or([{name: /#{attributes[:name]}/}, {email: /#{attributes[:email]}/i}])
```

This will return documents that has a `name` property with the value from `attributes[:name]` or documents that has `email` property with the value from `attributes[:email]`

Does this answer your question?